# command to convert windows path to unix path using cygwin inside a file

Tags: windows, unix, sed, path, cygwin

I need to convert a windows path to unix path inside a file before running make. I m running a make build using windows box because of one software(IDE). So using cygwin to run the build.

The windows path is:

```
c:/Program Files (x86)/xxxxxx/Bin/xxx.exe
```

and wants to change to:

```
/cygdrive/c/Program Files/xxxxx/Bin/xxxx.exe
```

I know i can use cygpath but that will only give me the converted unix path. I was thinking may be if i can use a sed command to make the change inside the file.

I m new to unix so if someone can help and give me the complete command that will be a great help

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't understand why `cygpath` is unsuitable.

Comment: Glen thanks for replying.                                                              I want to change the path inside the file. I dont want to edit the file and commit it. I want to change it during the build. That's why if i can use grep and sed somehow to make that change??

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -i 's#c:/Program Files (x86)/#/cygdrive/c/Program Files#' YourFile
```

Do the job but of you are coming from winDOwS world path separator is not the same as unix and is normaly `\` and in this case you certainly need

```
sed -i 's#c:\\Program Files (x86)\\#/cygdrive/c/Program Files#;s#\\#/#g' YourFile
```

Comment: Hello NeronLeVelu                                                            I tried your command and it only changed Program files (x86) to Program files but did not replaced c: with /cygdrive/c/

Comment: add the option `-e` to be sure sed take `(` as char and not regex group